# About proof of theorem (T is normal if and only if there exists an orthonormal basis for V consisting of eigenvectors of T)

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Definition: Let V be an inner product space, and let T be a linear operator on V. Say T is normal if $TT^{*} =T^{*}T$.

Theorem: Let T be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional complex inner product space V Then T is normal if and only if there exists an orthonormal basis for V consisting of eigenvectors of T.

How to prove this? A sketch is appreciated.

Comment: I've left a very similar comment on your other post, but to briefly reiterate: the spectral theorem is a standard result.  Proofs are available in textbooks and online.  It is hard to know what exactly you mean by a "simple" and "easy to understand" because these are subjective criteria, so please clarify what you mean.

Comment: For instance: this theorem (the spectral theorem) can be proven as a direct consequence of the Schur theorem (cf. Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*).  Arguably, this is a very easy proof to understand, but it relies on a powerful result.  Another approach requires a longer proof with more pieces that require understanding, but is perhaps more intuitive because it is done in a geometric but "coordinate-free" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T : X\rightarrow X$ is a linear transformation on a complex inner product space $X$, then $T$ is normal iff $T^*T=TT^*$. This is equivalent to
$$
             \|Tx\|^2=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle = \langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\langle TT^*x,x\rangle=\|T^*x\|^2,\;\;\; x\in X.
$$
Therefore, if $T^2x=0$, then $T^*Tx=0$ follows from the above, which implies that $Tx=0$ because
$$
         0 = \langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\|Tx\|^2 \implies Tx=0.
$$
Consequently, the minimal polynomial for $T$ has no repeated roots, which proves that $T$ is diagonalizable.

To show that the eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal, suppose that $Tx=\lambda x$ and $Ty=\mu y$ for some $\mu\ne\lambda$. Then, $x\perp y$ because
$$
    |\lambda-\mu|^2\langle x,y\rangle=(\lambda\overline{\lambda}-\lambda\overline{\mu}-\overline{\lambda}\mu+\mu\overline{\mu})\langle x,y\rangle \\
   =\langle T^*Tx,y\rangle-\langle Tx,Ty\rangle-\langle T^*x,T^*y\rangle+\langle x,TT^*y\rangle \\
   =\langle Tx,Ty\rangle-\langle Tx,Ty\rangle-\langle T^*x,T^*y\rangle+\langle T^*x,T^*y\rangle=0
$$
It follows that $T$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. The converse that $T$ is normal if it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors can be proved by directly showing $T^*T=TT^*$.

Comment: how $ker(T^2)=ker(T)$ implies its minimal polynomial has no repeated root?

Comment: Apply this same type of reasoning to other factors in a month minimal polynomial.

Comment: I also don't understand why $Tx=0$ implies that the minimal polynomial of $T$ has no repeated roots.